# scd2 table implementation in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, scd2

I am trying to create a SCD (slowly changing dimension) type 2 table in BigQuery without using any DML's

**test schema :**

`id | date | name | valid_from | valid_to | flag`

I need to capture the name changes for a specific `id`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can create artificially date partitioned tables to achieve this. This way, each date's data is unique and can be accessed by `` `select distinct column from `dataset.table$yyyymmdd;` `` or for all the history, just do `select distinct column from dataset.table;`. Also, you can always overwrite/append to a given date's partition without harming others.